# Dockerfile won't install cron

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cron, dockerfile, debian

I am trying to install cron via my Dockerfile, so that docker-compose can create a dedicated cron container by using a different entrypoint when it's built, which will regularly create another container that runs a script, and then remove it. I'm trying to follow the Separating Cron From Your Application Services section of this guide: https://www.cloudsavvyit.com/9033/how-to-use-cron-with-your-docker-containers/

I know that order of operation is important and I wonder if I have that misconfigured in my Dockerfile:

```
FROM swift:5.3-focal as build

RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN=true \
    && apt-get -q update \
    && apt-get -q dist-upgrade -y \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /build

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cron
COPY example-crontab /etc/cron.d/example-crontab
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/example-crontab &&\
    crontab /etc/cron.d/example-crontab

COPY ./Package.* ./
RUN swift package resolve

COPY . .

RUN swift build --enable-test-discovery -c release

WORKDIR /staging

RUN cp "$(swift build --package-path /build -c release --show-bin-path)/Run" ./
RUN [ -d /build/Public ] && { mv /build/Public ./Public && chmod -R a-w ./Public; } || true
RUN [ -d /build/Resources ] && { mv /build/Resources ./Resources && chmod -R a-w ./Resources; } || true

# ================================
# Run image
# ================================
FROM swift:5.3-focal-slim

RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN=true && \
    apt-get -q update && apt-get -q dist-upgrade -y && rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN useradd --user-group --create-home --system --skel /dev/null --home-dir /app vapor

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build --chown=vapor:vapor /staging /app

USER vapor:vapor

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["./Run"]
CMD ["serve", "--env", "production", "--hostname", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8080"]
```

This is relevant portion of my docker-compose file:

```
services:
  app:
    image: prizmserver:latest
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
      <<: *shared_environment
    volumes:
      - $PWD/.env:/app/.env
    links:
      - db:db
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    # user: '0' # uncomment to run as root for testing purposes even though Dockerfile defines 'vapor' user.
    command: ["serve", "--env", "production", "--hostname", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8080"]
  cron:
    image: prizmserver:latest
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    command: ["cron", "-f"]
```

This is my `example-scheduled-task.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
timestamp=`date +%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M:%S`
echo "System path is $PATH at $timestamp"
```

And this is my crontab file:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/sh /example-scheduled-task.sh
```

My script `example-scheduled-task.sh` and my crontab `example-crontab` live inside my application folder where this `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` live.

Why won't my cron container launch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a multistage build, only the last `FROM` will be used to generate final image.

E.g., for next example, the `a.txt` only could be seen in the first stage, can't be seen in the final image.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster

WORKDIR /tmp
RUN touch a.txt
RUN ls /tmp

FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN ls /tmp
```

**Execution:**

```
# docker build -t abc:1 . --no-cache
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/6 : FROM python:3.9-slim-buster
 ---> c2f204720fdd
Step 2/6 : WORKDIR /tmp
 ---> Running in 1e6ed4ef521d
Removing intermediate container 1e6ed4ef521d
 ---> 25282e6f7ed6
Step 3/6 : RUN touch a.txt
 ---> Running in b639fcecff7e
Removing intermediate container b639fcecff7e
 ---> 04985d00ed4c
Step 4/6 : RUN ls /tmp
 ---> Running in bfc2429d6570
a.txt
tmp6_uo5lcocacert.pem
Removing intermediate container bfc2429d6570
 ---> 3356850a7653
Step 5/6 : FROM ubuntu:16.04
 ---> 065cf14a189c
Step 6/6 : RUN ls /tmp
 ---> Running in 19755da110b8
Removing intermediate container 19755da110b8
 ---> 890f13e709dd
Successfully built 890f13e709dd
Successfully tagged abc:1
```

Back to your example, you copy crontab to the stage of `swift:5.3-focal`, but the final stage is `swift:5.3-focal-slim` which won't have any crontab.

**EDIT:**

For you, the compose for cron also needs to update as next:

```
cron:
    image: prizmserver:latest
    entrypoint: cron
    command: ["-f"]
```

`cron` don't need to use `/bash` to start, directly use `cron` to override the `entrypoint` could make the trick.

Comment: moving the three cron commands to after `FROM swift:5.3-focal-slim` has the same result, no cron container. Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: What's output of `docker-compose logs cron`?

Comment: Running that in my application base folder just says `attaching to`

Comment: Edit answer according to your comments.

Comment: That most recent edit didn't seem to work. Also, the output of `docker-compose logs cron` is still `attaching to`. Is there a different solution?

Comment: `docker-compose ps` still show the `cron` container exit? Have you ever to use `docker-compose down` to clean the container first?

Comment: No. `docker-compose down` helped! At least now I'm getting an error message: `ERROR: for cron  Cannot start service cron: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: exec: "cron": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown`

Comment: Please do `docker-compose up -d --build` to rebuild the Dockerfile. The docker image is still old, which means the `cron` installed in the first stage, don't forget `apt-get install -y cron` in final stage.

Comment: That did it! Cleaning the build was a key part. Thanks.